# Escape < in kbd

Tags: support, markdown

I would like to type S-(left bracket)LEFT (right bracket) inserted as keyboard. How to escape the (bracket)?

The problem is seen in question - [How to type S-<LEFT> during indent-rigidly?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/43734/how-to-type-s-left)

where LEFT for the time being is not enclosed in (brackets).

Check @npostavs answer:

<kbd>S-<LEFT></kbd>

@Gilles answer with kbd enclosure added:

<kbd>`S-<LEFT>`</kbd>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are literal characters that one would type on the computer (e.g. read in the interactive help or typed in the `kbd` function), so use [inline code markup](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code-spans).

```
`S-<LEFT>`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HTML character entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_entities#HTML_character_references) for angle brackets:

```
<kbd>S-&lt;LEFT&gt;</kbd>
```

Renders as

<kbd>S-<LEFT></kbd>